# Help with c wire on American standard air handler

Tags: wiring

there is no"C" indicated. Model TWE040E13FB
 I have taken pictures of the connections and looked at the wiring diagram however I cannot figure out which wire is any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Can you post the photos to [imgur](http://imgur.com) then link them here?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the schematic...

> [image]

The red wire is `R`, while the blue wire is `C`.